# Python time module output error with now.strftime()

Tags: python, time, output

I've tried to write a little script, giving out the actual system time by pressing enter.

As you can see below, the output is 18:51:16. After waiting 8 minutes and pressing enter, I receive first 18:51:18, pressing enter a second time, Idle shows the real time-value. This happens every time when I wait a couple of minutes. 
It's an endless loop, so I tried to reset the value of now.strftime('%H %M %S') with None or del command but with the same results as before.

```
import time

while True:
now = datetime.datetime.now()
text = input() 
if text == "":
    now.strftime('%H %M %S')

    print(now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

else:
    print("you typed some text before pressing enter")`
```

[image]

Any idea?

Best regards

Comment: What's the right indent of your code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop, you first retrieve the current time, and then you wait for the user's input. The user can wait as long as they want to respond, even days, and when they finally do respond, the `now` variable will be used. The problem with this is that `now` has the old time.

To fix this, put the `now` variable after your `input`. This way, you retrieve the current time of when the user pressed enter. One possible way to do that is below.

```
import time

while True:
    text = input()
    if text == "":
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    else:
        print("you typed some text before pressing enter")`
```

Comment: Great, if this was the answer to your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the green arrow.